# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'gridster-item'

Tags: lazy-loading, angular9

I know that something like this has been answered many times. But I think my case is different. I am using a project and a library. The component resides in the library. I am implementing the library component in the project like this:

```
 <div fxLayout="column" fxFill>
    <lib-component></lib-component>
</div>
```

The component itself has something like this:

```
 <div *ngIf="!expandedMode"></div>
```

But if I change the component implementation to this:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFill>
    <div *ngIf="true">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
</div>
```

Then I have no problem. That tells me that the library is not loading.

So, I guess my question actually is about how to load or probably preload libraries?

I am also lazy loading the module that uses library's component.

Hope, that clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use lazy component and want to use imports (e.g CommonModule), you need to create NgModule with target component in declarations there in the same file as your component

in lazy.component.ts

```
@Component({ ... }) 
export class LazyComponent 

@NgModule({ 
  declarations: [LazyComponent],
  imports: [ModuleYouNeedToImport]
}) 
export class SomeModule {}
```

in other.component.ts

```
import('./lazy.component.ts').then(({ LazyComponent }) => LazyComponent)
```

Comment: How a component file can be a module in the same time?